# DISCORD.JS HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I get this error randomly when I launch my bot, any help?

```js
0|index    | HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request.
0|index    |     at RequestHandler.execute (/path/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:93:15)
0|index    |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
0|index    |     at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:62:3)
0|index    |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:525:9)
0|index    |     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
0|index    |     at async RequestHandler.push (/path/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
0|index    |   code: 500,
0|index    |   method: 'post',
0|index    |   path: '/channels/774044054513254412/messages'
0|index    | }
```

does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: A request took longer than the specified `restRequestTimeout` (15 seconds by default), and was aborted to not lock up the request handler. It can be an internal server error on Discord's side or just a slow connection. In the case of the latter, the `restRequestTimeout` option in [ClientOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) can be increased to prevent future `AbortErrors`.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you!